# Python 3 + Selenium 3: ActionChain use in a loop throws WebDriverException

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, action

I am trying to make a program which will go to a page that has a lot of links, open the first X many links in new tabs and do something on those pages.

But using ActionChains to open the pages is causing this exception on the second iteration of the loop:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "autoPage.py", line 74, in <module>
    ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys_COMMAND).click(link).key_up(Keys_COMMAND).perform()
  File "usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py", line 80, in perform
    self.w3c_actions.perform()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/actions/action_builder.py", line 76, in perform
    self.driver.execute(Command.W3C_ACTIONS, enc)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: inputState is undefined
```

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50276598/webdriverexception-message-typeerror-rect-is-undefined) and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302300/python-selenium-cannot-perform-the-right-click-in-the-consecutive-loop) to a similar issues with no luck, and I'm basically doing [this code snippet on github](https://gist.github.com/lrhache/7686903) but in a loop.

Here is the script:

```py
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("the website")
main_window = driver.current_window_handle

numLinksToGoThrough = 2;
text = "keyword"
for i in range(numLinksToGoThrough):
    print("I=i")
    link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@data-automation, "%s")]' % text)[i]
    ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.COMMAND).click(link).key_up(Keys.COMMAND).perform()

    sleep(3); #wait for page to load a bit

    driver.switch_to_window(main_window)

    print("Handle job action")

    sleep(2); # placeholder

    print("End handle job action")
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 'w')
    browser.switch_to_window(main_window)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys_COMMAND).click(link).key_up(Keys_COMMAND).perform()
.
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: inputState is undefined
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** was unable to `perform()` the **Actions** within the **Browsing Context** i.e. **Firefox Browser** session.

---

However, to open the new tabs through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and `click()` simultaneously instead of using `Keys.COMMAND` you need to use `Keys.CONTROL` as follows:

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(link).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to open a link embeded in a webelement with in the main tab, in a new tab of the same window using Control + Click of Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57730636/how-to-open-a-link-embeded-in-a-webelement-with-in-the-main-tab-in-a-new-tab-of/57733103#57733103)
- [Opening a new tab using Ctrl + click combination in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201035/opening-a-new-tab-using-ctrl-click-combination-in-selenium-webdriver/46214265#46214265)