# Selenium Python ActionChain preform method

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, action

I need selenium and python to do the key combo <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so that it inserts a new line without sending a message (`\n` sends the message), and with this code it doesn't produce an error, but it also doesn't create a new line. *`message_box`* variable is already defined and the messages there do show up.

Code trials:

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
message_box.send_keys("test1")
action.key_down(Keys.SHIFT)
action.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
action.key_up(Keys.SHIFT)
message_box.send_keys("test2")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain the events in an [ActionChains()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59195010/7429447) and perform them in a chain using either of the following solutions:

- Using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>RETURN</kbd>:

  ```
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(message_box).send_keys("test1").key_down(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys(Keys.RETURN).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys("test2").perform()
  ```
- Using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd>:

  ```
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(message_box).send_keys("test1").key_down(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys("test2").perform()
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```