# How to press right arrow in Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium version 4.7.2
I use Anaconda and installed Selenium over Anaconda wit conda command.

How to press left arrow in Selenium?

**My project has below libraries**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import random
import time
```

**Code:**

I use this code structure it works, it clicks, but i want Selenium to press right arrow on keyboard.
How can i do this?

```
next = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='_abl-']//div[@class='_abm0']//*[@aria-label='Next']")
next.click()
```

I make a search and found this.
Arrow Key – Right
Keys.ARROW_RIGHT

But i have no idea about coding it.

Thanks for your help
Thanks for all comments

Comment: Title says right arrow, post body says left arrow.  Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To press <kbd><-</kbd> key once you have to use the [*ActionChains()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59195010/7429447) involving [`key_down(Keys.ARROW_LEFT)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.key_down) method followed by [`key_up(Keys.ARROW_LEFT)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.key_up) method as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.ARROW_LEFT).key_up(Keys.ARROW_LEFT).perform()
```

---

### tl; dr

Link to documentations:

- [Keyboard actions](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/keyboard/)
- [selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains)

Comment: Thanks
When i try 

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.ARROW_LEFT).key_up(Keys.ARROW_LEFT).perform()

driver is underlined and I got an error
'driver is not defined'
How can i fix this? Thanks

Comment: Thanks very much ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.ARROW_LEFT).key_up(Keys.ARROW_LEFT).perform() worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code to simulate arrow keys:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
```

for Left Arrow:

```
<WebElement>.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT)
```

for Right Arrow:

```
<WebElement>.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT)
```